# How to pass dynamic Form value while muliple files uploading using uploadify

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Initially I pass a key value as '0' after uploaded 1st file out of remaining 4 files key value changed by 'onuploadcomplete()' function, then i need to pass this value to next file uploading.is it possible to send a dynamic value(formData) to controller while muliple files option true.

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'formData'         : {'someKey' : $('#keyvalue').val()},
        'multi'            : true,
        'uploadScript'     : '/uploadifive.php',        
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file,data) {
            if(parseInt(data)>0)
             {
                  $('#keyvalue').val(data);
             }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I handled this in Controller level using Tempdata[],before returning object form serverside i stored that value in Tempdata.